# Display Confusion Matrix properly -

Tags: classification, python, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

I am trying to print the confusion matrix, but it is getting wrapped after few columns (or characters).
I have tried several settings but didn't help:

```
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.width', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', 1000)
```

This is how it looks at present -

[image]

Any help which setting will make it align in a single row?

Answer (score 0):

It was so silly on my part.

Confusion matrix is of data type `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>` and I was trying Pandas setting.

This resolved my concern => `np.set_printoptions(linewidth = 1000)`